# Error while accessing register variable value in ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to access register variable value in another task but i am getting an error and even knowing that I might be making a mistake but can't figure out.I would appreciate the help.
the code i have is:

```
hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ec2_vpc_net:
        name: Module_dev2
        cidr_block: 10.10.0.0/16
        region: us-east-1
        tags:
          module: ec2_vpc_net
          this: works
        tenancy: default
      register: vpc_v

    - name: show the VPC info
      debug: 
        var: vpc_v

    - ec2_vpc_igw:
        vpc_id: "{{ vpc_v.stdout.id }}"
        state: present
      register: igw
```

And the error i am getting is

```
TASK [ec2_vpc_igw] ***************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/kamaljit/Desktop/v3/playbooks/vpc_cr.yaml:20
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'id'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/kamaljit/Desktop/v3/playbooks/vpc_cr.yaml': line 20, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - ec2_vpc_igw:\n      ^ here\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ec2_vpc_net:
        name: Module_dev2
        cidr_block: 10.10.0.0/16
        region: us-east-1
        tags:
          module: ec2_vpc_net
          this: works
        tenancy: default
      register: vpc_v

    - name: show the VPC info
      debug: 
        var: vpc_v

    - ec2_vpc_igw:
        vpc_id: "{{ vpc_v.vpc.id }}"
        state: present
        region: us-east-1
      register: igw
```

was the correct code

Register variables can be by variable_name.module.attribute i guess. Thanks